# Using factory within controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I have simple module with controller and factory. I want to use factory within my controller.
So I should add the name of factory within my function() of controller. Adding this, so my controller doesnt work anymore (blank page, no errors)

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngAnimate'])
app.factory('Socket', function($scope) { ... });
```

My controller **works** if:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams, $timeout) {...});
```

My controller **does not work** if:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams, $timeout, Socket) {...});
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert `$scope` into a service in angular, because it has no meaning in the context of services. `$scope` is for controllers only, so remove the `$scope` dependency from your service:
`app.factory('Socket', function() { ... });`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was not $scope in the service. I got an error message after clearing the local storage. Socket was not defined. Problem is resolved now.